# Controls in UpdatePanel losing JQuery Events

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a button that is within an updatepanel control.  The button's click event has a function defined for it through JQuery.  Once the async postback completes the JQuery event fails to fire when the button is clicked subsequently.  **What do I need to do to correct this behavior and maintain the JQuery event attachment to the button's click event once it has been refreshed asynchronously?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

put your jquery event handler binding inside the following function

```
function pageLoad(sender,args) {

    // binding code here, for example
    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        // do something when the click event is raised
    });

}
```

`pageLoad` is executed after every postback, synchronous or asynchronous. `pageLoad` is a reserved function name in ASP.NET AJAX that is for this purpose. `$(document).ready()` on the other hand, is executed only once, when the DOM is initially ready/loaded.

See this [Overview of  ASP.NET AJAX client lifecycle events](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx)

Comment: I've added an example event handler. The "magic" is in the function name `pageLoad`, which is a reserved function that will execute when the page posts back, syncrhonously or asynchronously. It's analogous to setting up a function to execute using `Sys.Application.add_load(handler);`

Comment: Thank you very much, just implemented this and it works great! +1