# Trigger Click event using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to trigger an ASP.NET button using jQuery 
Target button placed in an Updatepanel

jQuery Code :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.ViewDetail').click(function (e) {
        var ID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('ExpID');
        $("#hflIdentityID").val(ID);
        $("#btnLoadBills").trigger('click');
        $("#ExpenseBills").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
        });
```

Mark Up code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DetailBillUpdatepanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="btnLoadGrid" style="display: none;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLoadBills" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"
                        Text="Button" />
                </div>
               GridView is Here...
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Behind Code :

```
Protected Sub btnLoadBills_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoadBills.Click
        grvExpenseBills.DataSource = tadok.Data.DataRepository.EdlBlpProvider.GetByEdlId(hflIdentityID.Value)
        grvExpenseBills.DataBind()
       End Sub
```

Why event does not fire ?

Comment: for this you have to read [Ajax Client Life-Cycle Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your jquery event handler binding inside the following function

```
function pageLoad(sender,args) {

    // binding code here, for example
    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        // do something when the click event is raised
    });

}
```

`pageLoad` is executed after every postback, synchronous or asynchronous. pageLoad is a reserved function name in ASP.NET AJAX that is for this purpose. `$(document).ready()` on the other hand, is executed only once, when the DOM is initially ready/loaded.

This has been taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001906/controls-in-updatepanel-losing-jquery-events)

Comment: It works but something is strange for me , because my selector is not in Updatepanel why should i rebind click event outside Document.Ready ?!

Answer (score 2):

#btnLoadBills does not represent the actual ID of button, try to use the following

```
$('#<%= btnLoadBills.ClientID %>').trigger('click');
```

Comment: But ClientIdMode valued static.

Comment: I also tried Dynamic ClientID and $('#<%= btnLoadBills.ClientID %>').trigger('click');
 it does not work yet

Comment: What is the aim of this "return false;" in your $(document).ready, shall you try without it??

Comment: Thanks Ahmed , I did rebind my click event after postback regards Thomas answer and it works right now.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure of this, but shall you try to add btnLoadBills as a trigger of updatepanel (either synchronous or asynchronous trigger), and try just for try.
Also, I hope if you can check button functionality itself apart from trigger/click functions just to check this there is no something in the middle preventing button functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for that kind of situation

```
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);


            function endRequestHandler(sender, args)

            {

                 $('.ViewDetail').click(function (e) {
                 var ID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('ExpID');
                 $("#hflIdentityID").val(ID);
                 $("#btnLoadBills").trigger('click');
                 $("#ExpenseBills").dialog("open");
                 return false;
             });

            }
```